# How to get URLs from Chrome

Tags: c++, google-chrome, url, microsoft-ui-automation, geturl

You can get the Chrome URL using uiautomation.
However, Chrome UI menu is not visible on some PCs.
Is there another way?

UI Menu Success:
[image: UI Spy OK]

UI Menu Failed:
[image: UI Spy KO]

```
varPropAddr.bstrVal = SysAllocString(L"Address and search bar");

m_pAutomation->CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, varPropAddr, &pAddrCondition

pRoot->FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, pAddrCondition, &pAddrBar);

SysFreeString(varPropAddr.bstrVal);

hr = E_FAIL;

hr = pAddrBar->GetCurrentPatternAs(UIA_ValuePatternId, __uuidof(IUIAutomationValuePattern), (void**)&pURLValuePattern);

if (pURLValuePattern != NULL)
{
BSTR bstrUrl;
HRESULT hr = pURLValuePattern->get_CurrentValue(&bstrUrl);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{   
bReadOnly = TRUE;
strUrl = (LPWSTR)bstrUrl;
//m_strUrl_Chrome = strUrl;

SysFreeString(bstrUrl);
bstrUrl = NULL;
}
}
```

chrome Update, Reinstall chrome, chrome option reset

I have successfully obtained the Chrome URL with the above code.
However, some PCs did not get the URL because I could not check the UI menu.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613115/microsoft-uiautomation-isnt-always-working-on-some-computers-c-sharp

Comment: The problem is not solved. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I have no solution. Try to find what is different on the failing PCs (os version, chrome version, .dotnet version). Also, try to use inspect.exe from Windows SDK.